# How many activities can i use in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

If I use more than 500 activities in an android studio for making a project is it going to any problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many activities as you want, but the app would be huge and the projet would take ages to load and compile. So, you can, but you shouldn't have that many. Choose a good pattern to work with and make the code as short as possible.